# PDO equivalent to MDB2 autoExecute()

Tags: php, pdo

Alright, so normally Google and Stackoverflow are on my side, and I have good luck finding answers, but I could really use some help rewriting this MDB2 query execution for PDO.
Most functions for MDB2 have a one-to-one equivalent in PDO, or something really close. However, according to this [documentation](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.mdb2.intro-auto.php), it auto prepares a query, and executes it. Here's this old code below:

```
$this->db->autoExecute('material_sets',
                                array('material_set' => filter_var($_REQUEST['material_set'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),
                                  'selectmethod' => $_REQUEST['selectmethod'],
                                  'selectoptions' => $selectoptions,
                                  'companyid' => $this->companyid),
                                MDB2_AUTOQUERY_INSERT);
```

Is there any modern PDO equivalent to this? If there isn't, I could really really use some help rewriting this, or at least a nudge in the right direction.

```
    $query = 'INSERT INTO `material_sets` (material_set, selectmethod, selectoptions, companyid) VALUES (?,?,?,?)';
    $this->db->prepare($query)->execute(array($_REQUEST['material_set'],$_REQUEST['selectmethod'],$selectoptions,$this->companyid));
```

I believe this snippet I wrote above may be an equivalent, but could use a sanity check here.

Edit: So I went to test this out, and it's throwing this error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute()`

Which is just silly. I even tried to separate everything for sanity's sake, and it isn't liking that either.

```
$data = ['material_set' => filter_var($_REQUEST['material_set'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),
        'selectmethod' => $_REQUEST['selectmethod'],
        'selectoptions' => $selectoptions,
        'companyid' => $this->companyid];
        $query = 'INSERT INTO `material_sets` (material_set, selectmethod, selectoptions, companyid) VALUES (?,?,?,?)';
        
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute($data);
```

I feel like it's dying at execute() for a reason that PHP can't properly output an error for.

I'm assuming `$data` is being formatted improperly, and dying? I need to investigate further.

Comment: Not directly.  But you can just prepare a query and then execute it, it's only one extra line

Comment: Hey ADyson, for sanity's sake, does this PDO code equivalent look right to you? Its in my edit above. Sorry, not sure how to format it in comment.

Comment: No worries, it's far better added to the question anyway, that's how it's supposed to be done! Anyway, I don't know anything about mdb2, but from a glance it looks like the PDO version ought to do the same thing...does the query work as you expected when you test it?

Comment: Sadly, it's dying on `execute`. I'm wondering if the `$data` array I made is being improperly filled.

Comment: So...even when you run the separated-out version, you get the `call to undefined method PDO::execute() ` error?? Or something else?

Comment: Yeah dude, it's ridiculous. I'm going to dump `data` and see what's going on. I mean, even if some of those value fields were null, it should still work, right? Additionally, I know my database connection is good, because I have multiple fetch queries accessing data from the database. Is it perhaps an `INSERT` permissions issue? I'm just spit balling at this point, because I'm stumped haha.

Comment: That error can't be related to `$data` I don't think. It's not getting as far as parsing that, if it's telling you that execute() doesn't exist. But it doesn't make sense, the error, because you're calling execute() on a PDOStatement object, not a PDO object. Are you _sure_ what you've shown is the exact code you're executing, and that the error is coming from this bit of the code?

Comment: Also, for _my_ sanity, please do a `var_dump($stmt);` on the line before `$stmt->execute($data);` just to double-check what `$stmt` really is.

Comment: `$stmt` is dumping this: ```object(PDOStatement)#59 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(99) "INSERT INTO `material_sets` (material_set, selectmethod, selectoptions, companyid) VALUES (?,?,?,?)" }```

Comment: Then, to be quite honest, I don't see how you could possibly be getting the error you're saying you do from the code you've shown.

Comment: Oh god, that's not good haha. I swear I haven't changed anything between me copying it and pasting it here. I'll keep this updated as I find out what is happening. I appreciate the help though, and the confirmation that I'm not losing my mind haha.

Comment: The usual reason people encounter this error is what's explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23551121/5947043 . But that's not what you're doing here, **unless** you're doing something like inadvertently editing a different copy of the code than the one your webserver is executing - that has happened to people before.

Comment: Hey, before I'm off for the weekend, I think I found out what the hell was happening. So their is another query that is broken under it that wasn't fixed yet, and it was throwing an error at my line that was written correctly! Your link actually helped me put the pieces together. The funny part is the error like was NOT where the bad execution was written, but rather the code I kept sharing with you. Totally misleading error message, but I will update this monday with a 100% concrete answer. I can't thank you enough for the help this afternoon.

Comment: No worries, glad you sorted it. Strange that PHP got the line numbers of the error wrong though, that doesn't normally happen.